# Powershell Convert to JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I want to convert the data in the following script to JSON, can anyone let me know how to include [] in the JSON using powershell.
My script:

```
$URL = " http://localhost:4200/api/testinglabproject/test-run"
$projectShortName = "NES"
$testPlanName = "TestManager"
$deviceName = "testt"
$nodeManagerResourceName = "nm-4c2f1575-00fd-4363-b88a-2fb3cf587223"
$hostname = "DSTW8Y2.bla.is.abc.com"
$resourceName = "hs-515a8129-1aa0-4a14-847b-210022fe9cd7"
$hardwareSolutionType = "testt"
$emailId = "abc@gmail.com"

$data = @{
projectShortName=$projectShortName
testPlanName=$testPlanName
hardwareSolution=@{
hardwareSolutionItemList = 
@{deviceName = $deviceName
nodeManagerResourceName =$nodeManagerResourceName
hostname = $hostname}


hardwareSolutionMetadataList = "[]"
resourceName = $resourceName
hardwareSolutionType = $hardwareSolutionType
}
emailId = $emailId
}

$jsondata = $data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
Write-Host $jsondata
```

The resulting JSON should be like this:

```
{
"projectShortName": <projectShortName>,
"testPlanName": <planName>,
"hardwareSolution": {
    "hardwareSolutionItemList": [{"deviceName": <deviceName>,
    "nodeManagerResourceName": <NodeManagerResourceName>,
    "hostname": <hostName>}],
    "hardwareSolutionMetadataList": [],
    "resourceName": <HardwareSolutionResourceName>,
    "hardwareSolutionType": <hwstName>
},
"emailId": <emailID>
}
```

Comment: `hardwareSolutionMetadataList = @()` should do the trick. This creates an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stripped all those superfluous variables and replaced the string `"[]"` with an *actual* PowerShell array `@()` for the `hardwareSolutionMetadataList` key:

```
$data = @{
  testPlanName = "TestManager"
  projectShortName = "NES"
  hardwareSolution = @{
    hardwareSolutionItemList = @{
      deviceName = "testt"
      nodeManagerResourceName = "nm-4c2f1575-00fd-4363-b88a-2fb3cf587223"
      hostname = "DSTW8Y2.bla.is.abc.com"
    }
    hardwareSolutionMetadataList = @()
    resourceName = "hs-515a8129-1aa0-4a14-847b-210022fe9cd7"
    hardwareSolutionType = "testt"
  }
  emailId = "abc@gmail.com"
}

$jsondata = $data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
Write-Host $jsondata
```

PowerShell's idea of JSON formatting is a bit odd, but structurally it's OK.

```
{
    "hardwareSolution":  {
                             "hardwareSolutionItemList":  {
                                                              "deviceName":  "testt",
                                                              "hostname":  "DSTW8Y2.bla.is.abc.com",
                                                              "nodeManagerResourceName":  "nm-4c2f1575-00fd-4363-b88a-2fb3cf587223"
                                                          },
                             "resourceName":  "hs-515a8129-1aa0-4a14-847b-210022fe9cd7",
                             "hardwareSolutionMetadataList":  [

                                                              ],
                             "hardwareSolutionType":  "testt"
                         },
    "testPlanName":  "TestManager",
    "emailId":  "abc@gmail.com",
    "projectShortName":  "NES"
}
```

You can use the `-Compress` parameter to remove the whitespace for uploading the JSON somewhere.

```
{"hardwareSolution":{"hardwareSolutionItemList":{"deviceName":"testt","hostname":"DSTW8Y2.bla.is.abc.com","nodeManagerResourceName":"nm-4c2f1575-00fd-4363-b88a-2fb3cf587223"},"resourceName":"hs-515a8129-1aa0-4a14-847b-210022fe9cd7","hardwareSolutionMetadataList":[],"hardwareSolutionType":"testt"},"testPlanName":"TestManager","emailId":"abc@gmail.com","projectShortName":"NES"}
```